# COM+ applications deployment behaves different on different systems

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-xp, com+

In order to give my COM+ application enough credentials I want its components to be instantiated under "Local Service" account.

When I create a server application with a wizard on Win2k3 it offers to choose under whom to instantiate components - "Local Service" is one of choices. But on WinXP "Local Service" is not offered at all in the wizard.

When I open the "Identity" tab of the COM+ application under Win2k3 there'a a handful of choises, "Local Service" included, and I can select any of them. But on WinXP the same "Identity" tab only offers "Interactive user".

What does this difference depend on? Does it depend on the system or on something else?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can determine [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30582459/com-identity-win2kwin2.aspx), "Interactive User" is almost but not entirely like "Local Service".

This discussion may also be interesting to you: http://www.windowskb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-xp-configuration/3378/Run-service-interactive-with-user-account-not

I'm voting to close and move to stackoverflow, where I suspect you'll get much better answers.